# automatically create a model object when an object of another table is created or updated in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models in Django and I want to automatically create an object of `History` when an object of `Food` is created or updated and set the `food_price` attribute of `History` to the `price` attribute of the created `Food` object. My purpose is to have a history of food change price. How can I achieve that?

My `models.py` is:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    food_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    f_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_food_t_image_name)
    DDD_data = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_food_d_image_name)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.category_id, self.price)

class History(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    food_id = models.IntegerField()
    food_price = models.IntegerField()
    history_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.id, self.food_id.name, self.food_id.price)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two ways.

#### First, use `__save__()` method in model.

In django model, (`models.Model`), there's `__save__` method. When model object saves, you can do an additional feature that inherits this method.

For more information, please check [official docs save()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects)

#### Second, use `signals`

Django supports many signals including `django.db.models.signals`. It includes `pre_save`, `post_save`, and so on. So before(after) saving model object, you can do sth in `signals`.

Please check [official docs signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/)

I think `__save__()` method is more fit to your purpose. So your code will be...

```
class Food(models.Model):
    food_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    f_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_food_t_image_name)
    DDD_data = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_food_d_image_name)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.category_id, self.price)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, *args, **kwargs):
        # you can add this for only existing model object
        if self.pk:
            # You can check if only 'price' field changed
            _original_food = Food.objects.get(id=self.pk)
            if _original_food.price != self.price:
                # do somthing here like saving history...
                History.objects.create(food_id=self.id, food_price=self.price)
                super(Food, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
        super(Food, self).save(force_insert, force_update, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is just example. You can add & modify your code. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I have a question seuling. when I already have a Food object Or I want to make a new, in both of them, the statements inside `if self.pk:` execute! I want to make a history object when a Food object creates and again make a history object when a Food object price updates.how to do that?

Comment: Sorry for late response. You mean you also want to track when food object created? Then you can add `else` after `if self.pk:`. It means `If self.pk is None:` and it means the object is created.